# Cannot find ecrm1095.mf

Tags: fonts, texlive

The TeXLive 2014 was installed as I usually install them: Selected ADVANCED, then selected the collections

- Essential programs and files
- Generic recommended
- LaTeX recommended
- Windows only
- Graphics and pictures
- Graphics and font utilities

Having done that, I tried one of my standard latex files and got the error message below. I understand it to be a missing font. In TeXLive 2013 no error message appeared.

Could anyone tell how I can add what is missing?

Hewe is what pdflatex tells me:

```
kpathsea: Running mktexmf tcrm1095.mf

The command name is C:\sys\texlive\bin\win32\mktexmf
name = tcrm1095, rootname = tcrm, pointsize = 1095
mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile!
Cannot find tcrm1095.mf.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font TS1/cmr/m/n/10.95=tcrm1095 at 10.95pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file no
t found.
<to be read again>
                   relax

l.159   \item C

               urved elements are shown with flat faces. This is found from ...
```

Comment: I don't know what others do, but I habitually install *everything*, as it generally saves me from troubles of this sort. Do you have serious disk space problems?

Comment: The file in question is part of the [`ec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ec) bundle (for me, `kpsewhich tcrm1095.mf` gives `/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/source/jknappen/ec/tcrm1095.mf`). So the obvious solution is to install the `ec` package using `tlmgr`: does that help?

Comment: Joseph, Your answer solved my problem, so when the ec package had been installed with the tlmgr install ec then the \begin{itemize} no longer gave an error message. Thnx.   Brent, LaTeX is used for output of a program of mine used by others. They complain about the huge space taken up by the TeXLive files. Therefore I try to restrain my installation to what is needed and nothing more.

Comment: @JosephWright: Your comment is now an answer. Post your own, if you wish (then you can remove mine, as you are a mod)

Answer (score 3):

@JosephWright answered this in the comments:

> The file in question is part of the [`ec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ec) bundle (for me, `kpsewhich tcrm1095.mf` gives `/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/source/jknappen/ec/tcrm1095.mf`). So the obvious solution is to install the `ec` package using `tlmgr`

or just

> habitually install everything

as @Brent.Longborough advised.

Answer (score 1):

On Debian, `apt-file` reveals that file to be part of the `texlive-fonts-recommended` package.